# How to best MySQL configuration in AWS RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have an e-commerce system which is currently deployed in EC2 instance. currently MySQL is in the same server and now that we are getting high traffic now and then, we're planning to use Autoscaling service and as we need to separate the database we gonna use RDS. Now the confusion is what configuration to use. how can i know how much RAM and CPU would be required for our system.
Currently, our server is c5.xlarge and avg CPU usage reached upto 70%-80% with MySQL utilizing max CPU.
So, what are the ways or factors that we need to consider while configuring MySQL in RDS?

Comment: If this is WooCommerce, say so; there are specific improvements to make with it.  If this is home-grown, say so _and_ show us the schema and main queries.  The solution may be as simple as improving an index.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.